# How to vertically center modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically center a modal. I searched a lot on Google but found nothing helpful. Here is my code:

```js
 function inactive(id, ths) {
   $("#confirmation").modal("show");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="confirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure you want to inactivate it?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" id="cval" placeholder="enter captcha">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I center it vertically?

Comment: Where on the screen does the modal appear?

Comment: at the top.and my navigation bar is overlaying modal.

Comment: onclick try to check the id

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not tested but you can try this

```
.yourElement{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: how can I check which button is clicked?

Comment: If the modal is larger than the viewport height then this solution will not work well as content will get cropped. Instead, you should simply do this on the container: 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 11):

There is a specific bootstrap class (v4.1) for this:

Add **.modal-dialog-centered** to *.modal-dialog* to vertically center the modal.

Source: *https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered*

Answer (score 7):

As it looks as a bootstrap modal, Checkout this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te7v0bed/)** (jsFiddle).

Try

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

By adding position and transform properties, you wouldn't get it to be centred across all widths and devices, plus calculating it all the time could be a tedious process. Here is what worked by styling just the '.modal-dialog' class

```
/* Center a bootstrap modal Vertically and horizontally */

.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

/* and Viola! */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```js
// Vertical centered modals
// you can give custom class like this // var modalVerticalCenterClass = ".modal.modal-vcenter";

var modalVerticalCenterClass = ".modal";
function centerModals($element) {
    var $modals;
    if ($element.length) {
        $modals = $element;
    } else {
        $modals = $(modalVerticalCenterClass + ':visible');
    }
    $modals.each( function(i) {
        var $clone = $(this).clone().css('display', 'block').appendTo('body');
        var top = Math.round(($clone.height() - $clone.find('.modal-content').height()) / 2);
        top = top > 0 ? top : 0;
        $clone.remove();
        $(this).find('.modal-content').css("margin-top", top);
    });
}
$(modalVerticalCenterClass).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    centerModals($(this));
});
$(window).on('resize', centerModals);
```

```css
/* scroll fixes */
.modal-open .modal {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* centering styles for jsbin */
html,
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
html {
  display:table;
}
body {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
body > .btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 vertically centered modal and scroll fixes</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap 3 vertically centered modal and scroll fixes">
    <!-- include bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  
<!-- include bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest (not tested cross-browser but should be ok):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<p>Container</p>
<div class="modal">
<p>Modal</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
position:relative;
}

.modal {
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto; 
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o9pbgnz5/

It's important that you set both `top:0` **and** `bottom:0`. Then, `margin-top:auto` and `margin-bottom:auto` should take care of the vertical centering. In this example, the shorthand 'margin:auto' centers it both horizontally and vertically.

P.S. Also works with `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

Centering the modal vertically can be done if you use CSS calc() function on the top CSS property. Let's say that the modal has a height of 600px. Using the vh unit with a value of 50 will get you the midpoint on the vertical height of the screen. Then you just need to subtract half of the height of the modal element.

```
#modal {
   position:  fixed;
   height: 600px;
   top: calc(50vh - 300px);
   z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap 4 or above you can simply use bootstrap classes modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered

```js
 function inactive(id, ths) {
   $("#confirmation").modal("show");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="confirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure you want to inactivate it?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" id="cval" placeholder="enter captcha">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```